# NO routing in VPN to client side

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn, openwrt, endian-firewall

I try to configure the following network structure in one dev VMWare environment.

```
     W.XP------|                            |-----W10
192.168.5.100  |                            |  192.168.4.100
               |                            |
               |                            | 
            Endian FW  -- VPN conn ----- OPENWRT as (Openvpn Server)
           192.168.5.1                     192.168.4.1     
         VPN IP 10.200.0.2                  VPN IP 10.200.0.1
```

I configured one TUN connection and is UP and I can do ping from VPN both sides 10.200.0.2 <--> 10.200.0.1.

The vmware virtual Switch is in promiscuous mode.

Y try ping from

Endian --> OPENVPN works eth0 192.168.4.1

Endian --> W10 works

W.XP --> openvpn not works. "Wrong IPTABLES? "

OPENVPN --> ENDIAN not works... ping to eth0 192.168.5.1

W10 --> Endian not works

W10 --> W.XP no works

In Openwrt I **added following routes:**

route add -net 192.168.5.0/24 gw 10.200.0.2

**And iptables conf:**

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.200.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

In Endian i **added following routes:**

route add -net 192.168.4.0/24 gw 10.200.0.1

**and iptables conf:**
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o openvpntun0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.200.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

I try to understand whats is wrong. But I can guess the problem is in IPTABLES filtering.